# How to delete the image path from a server using unlink in PHP?

Tags: php

I've almost finished my project but I'm stuck on a small problem I'm hoping to get help with. This is my first PHP/mysqli project and I'm still very "green". Any help is much appreciated.

I have been able to successfully upload and delete images from my database, however I can't seem to get the unlink command to delete the images from my server.

Please find below the code I am using in the background (hotel-imgdelete.php):

```
    <?php
    include_once 'db_connect.php';
    include_once 'functions.php';

    sec_session_start();

// confirm that the 'id' variable has been set
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
    // get the 'id' variable from the URL
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    // delete image from server
        $path = "../hotels/";
        $image = "name";
        unlink($path.$image);

    // delete record from database
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM hotels WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$id); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
    }
    $mysqli->close();

    // redirect user after delete is successful
    header("Location: ../home.php");
}
else
// if the 'id' variable isn't set, redirect the user
{
    header("Location: ../delete-hotel-images.php");
}

    ?>
```

This is the code I am using to view and select the images to delete
(delete-hotel-images.php)

```
    <?php

      // get the records from the database




                    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM hotels ORDER BY id"))

                    {
                            // display records if there are records to display
                            if ($result->num_rows > 0)
                            {                                        
                                    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
                                    {
                                         $row->id;
                        echo        "<div id='partner'><img src='hotels/" . $row->name . "'></a><br><br>";
                        echo        "<center><a href='#' onclick='delete_user(". $row->id . ")'>Delete</a></center></div>";

                                    }
                            }
                            // if there are no records in the database, display an alert message
                            else
                            {
                                    echo "No results to display!";
                            }
                    }
                    // show an error if there is an issue with the database query
                    else
                    {
                            echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
                    }

                    // close database connection
                    $mysqli->close();

            ?>
```

Comment: Do you have your errors turned on? I'm not sure you can use a relative path when you unlink. Try using a root path from the server like /var/www/...

Comment: print `$path.$image` right before you unlink. Is that the correct full path to the file you want to delete?

Comment: @ssnoboby - nothing happened, it didn't print because that file redirects to delete-hotel-images.php

Comment: Stop the redirect temporarily so you can see the value or simply capture the response using Dev Console of your browser.

Comment: I know the path is correct because i've been able to delete ALL the images from the server directory at once, I just can't get it to select the file to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your filesystem looks like, or what the file is supposed to be, but it looks like you're trying to delete "../hotels/name", since $image is set to the string "name".

I'm assuming this wasn't intentional so that could be the problem there. If, however, you are trying to delete a directory (since it appears to have no file extension) you will need to use "rmdir" and not "unlink".

How are the images laid out on your filesystem?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, The images are all in a folder on the server called hotels, the image file names are created randomly when the file is uploaded to the server. I somehow want to get the image, whose field in the db table is  called "name" to be deleted from the server when I delete the row from the db. I meant for `$image = "name";` to reference the fieldname of the image in the database. As I mentioned, I'm very new to this.

Comment: @ethan22 - error reporting is showing no error, the root path made no difference. it is still removing the row from the db but leaving the image on the server.

Comment: Hi SAmabb, the file path is as follow, for the images - `root/admin/hotels/random-image-name.jpg`, delete-hotel-images.php is in root/admin and hotel-imgdelete.php is in root/admin/includes

Comment: You will need to get the name from the table then before you call the unlink function. Query the table using the ID. I'm not sure how your table schema is, but it would look something like this "SELECT image_name_column FROM hotels WHERE id = ?".

Then using that name, pass it into your unlink call.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I've spent 3 days trying to work this out, nothing I've researched online has been any help. I think I'll just put this in the too hard basket. I don't really understand php and I think I'm probably too old now to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

sorted

```
        if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
    // get the 'id' variable from the URL
    $id = $_GET['id'];

            if  ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM hotels WHERE id=?"));
                {
                $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
                $stmt->execute();
                }
                $stmt->bind_result($id, $name);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $path = "../images/hotels/";
                $image = $name;
                unlink($path.$image);
                $stmt->close();

    include_once 'db_connect.php';
    include_once 'functions.php';



    // delete record from database
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM hotels WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$id); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
    }
    $mysqli->close();

    // redirect user after delete is successful
    header("Location: ../home.php");
}
else
// if the 'id' variable isn't set, redirect the user
{
    header("Location: ../delete-hotel-images.php");
}
```